awk - combine 2 steps into one
I need to read the output table of transmission-remote to determine if a download is taking place. This is currently achieved with
trans="transmission-remote 0.0.0.0:9092 -n $user:$pass -l"
[ "$($trans | awk '! /awk/ && /n[/]a/ {print $2}')" == "n/a" ] \
|| [[ $($trans | awk '! /awk/ && /%/ {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sort -n | head -n 1) -lt 100 ]]

It's looking for either the presence of string 'n/a' or a completion of <100%.
The way it's written it must probe 'transmission-remote' twice for the same table.
Sample table output:
ID  Done    Have     ETA          Up      Down  Ratio Status       Name
1   100%    3.38 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.00  Finished     Fish Documentary.mkv
2   100%    5.87 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Ethical Coding.pdf
3   100%    1.33 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.99  Finished     Bacon.jpg
4   100%    1.26 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Eggs.png
5   100%   10.89 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.00  Finished     Invest in gold.pdf
Sum:            23.63 GB               0.0     0.0

Is it possible to combine the awk arguments into one, or perhaps someone could suggest an easier or cleaner way to achieve the desired outcome?
The ultimate goal is to have the red LED on the NAS flash red when a download is taking place, and turn solid white when all downloads have completed.
The original script is here: https://pastebin.com/tKXc8mFW

After looking at the code in your pastebin post, I think this:
trans="transmission-remote 0.0.0.0:9092 -n $user:$pass -l"

while
 [ "$($trans | awk '! /awk/ && /n[/]a/ {print $2}')" == "n/a" ] \
 || [[ $($trans | awk '! /awk/ && /%/ {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sort -n | head -n 1) -lt 100 ]] \
 || find $dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read
do
 sleep 10
done

should be this (untested):
downloading() {
    transmission-remote '0.0.0.0:9092' -n "$user:$pass" -l |
        awk '($2 ~ "[/%]") && ($2+0 < 100){f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' ||
    find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read -r
}

while downloading; do
    sleep 10
done

Explanation:
I think the table in your question is probably sample input but it doesn't contain any of the values you say you want to find:

the presence of string 'n/a' or a completion of <100%

which I assume must be in the 2nd column given your code, so it's not useful for testing with.
If we modify that to contain some of those target values:
$ cat file
ID  Done    Have     ETA          Up      Down  Ratio Status       Name
1   100%    3.38 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.00  Finished     Fish Documentary.mkv
2    25%    5.87 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Ethical Coding.pdf
3   100%    1.33 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.99  Finished     Bacon.jpg
4    77%    1.26 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Eggs.png
5    n/a   10.89 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.00  Finished     Invest in gold.pdf

and change this:
trans="transmission-remote 0.0.0.0:9092 -n $user:$pass -l"

to this:
trans() { transmission-remote '0.0.0.0:9092' -n "$user:$pass" -l; }

to fix your other issue that you should store code in functions, not in variables (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and then change that to this:
trans() { cat file; }

for now just to let us test with the above input then it sounds like what you want is:
$ trans | awk '($2 ~ "[/%]") && ($2+0 < 100)'
2    25%    5.87 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Ethical Coding.pdf
4    77%    1.26 GB  Unknown      0.0     0.0   0.00  Idle         Eggs.png
5    n/a   10.89 GB  Done         0.0     0.0   1.00  Finished     Invest in gold.pdf

but given there's no expected output in your question that's just a guess.
It's also possible you may just want to get a success/fail exit status if any of the conditions are met in which case it'd be:
$ if trans | awk '($2 ~ "[/%]") && ($2+0 < 100){f=1; exit} END{exit !f}'; then
    echo "found it"
fi
found it

or if you want to do that in a loop calling trans once per second until the awk script exits with success (meaning no targets were found):
$ while trans | awk '($2 ~ "[/%]") && ($2+0 < 100){f=1; exit} END{exit !f}'; do
    echo "flash red"
    sleep 1
done
flash red
flash red
flash red
flash red


read returns false unless the input contains an unescaped newline character. So for instance it also return false on the output of printf '%s\n' 'file-ending-in-backslash\'. You need read -r to check that find reports at least one file (or read -r discard POSIXly).

@StéphaneChazelas I thought about fixing that for the OP too but figured it probably works for the files the OP actually has and it'd be getting too far away from their original question when I was already fixing their use of a variable to hold code and moving their conditional code into a function. I'd actually do files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; printf '%s\n' "$dir"/*) && (( "${#files}" )) or similar for that part of the script but haven't thought about it too much.

Or ls -A -- "$dir/" | grep -q '^'

Also note that awk '$2 ~ /[/%]/' returns an error in busybox awk, while awk '$2 ~ /[\/%]/' doesn't but matches on a b\c. awk '$2 ~ "[/%]"' would be portable.

I added the -r to the read. I'm surprised by busybox awk's behavior in both cases, especially the second one as the meaning of [\/] is explicitly defined by POSIX, but thanks for the heads up - I changed to the dynamic regexp syntax you suggested now.

Both yours and Stephen Kitt's code above work perfectly. Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me. I will upvote both comments when I have the required reputation to do so. All the best.

Thank you. One last question please if I can bother you quickly? Am I correct in saying that $2+0 is there to convert n/a to 0?

@TonyPuryer yes but also to convert 50% to 50.

The following AWK invocation will exit with success if “n/a” is found in the second column, or the second column is less than 100%, and fail otherwise:
awk 'BEGIN { r = 1 } $2 == "n/a" || ($2 ~ "%" && int($2) < 100) { r = 0; exit } END { exit r }'

In your script, that becomes
while
 $trans | awk 'BEGIN { r = 1 } $2 == "n/a" || ($2 ~ "%" && int($2) < 100) { r = 0; exit } END { exit r }' \
 || find $dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read
do
 sleep 10
done

The AWK script looks in column 2 for either “n/a” or a percentage value which is less than 100 when converted to an integer.

+1 especially for returning a status code instead of printing and comparing numbers / strings, which would've been the naive way to do it

That works perfectly. Thank you for giving up your time to help me with this.

Unfortunately I'm not able to upvote your comment as I'm a new user with low reputation, but will do so when I qualify.

If the answer solves your problem, you can accept it even with no reputation (using the big check mark).
